# ASP MVC DateTime Input behaving strange?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I've got a model with the attribute `ArrivalDate` which is annotated with:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

I've also set my globalisation variable in the `Web.config` file to:

```
 <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

For some reason when creating an editor on one of my views it's allowing various things but not what I'm after. I'm trying to get the format `30/12/2013`.

I can use:

- 30/Dec/2013 - which validates and saves fine
- 20/30/2013 - which passes validation but results in: `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
  The statement has been terminated.` when saving changes to the database (expected, but why does it pass validation).
- 30/December/2013 - which validates and saves fine

At first I thought I must need to use a lower case `m` but this doesn't seem to change anything?

Anyone got any ideas, I'm facing a brick wall at the moment?

EDIT: I should point out that when using `30/12/2013` it seems to fail validation with the following message: `The field Arrival Date must be a date.`

Comment: Why type of control are you using for the date?

Comment: Good question.. I'm just using the default `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArrivalDate)` for now, once I get it working I'll try and add on a fancier input field.

Comment: Are you using unobtrustive (JavaScript) validation when you said it passes/fails and then you get errors on the actual conversion to DateTime object? I was going to suggest you use a standard format string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm now wondering if the model binder is failing to take culture settings into account for the bind.

Comment: @ErikNoren I've not added anything fancy into the views. All I've done is generate a model & database. Generated the controller & views from that, then added via code first migrations the ArrivalDate DateTime attribute to the model. Now I'm trying to add that new attribute to the create form. One thing I am doing (for a certain user role is restrict some values and set the myself on the post action. I'm also using `ModelState.Clear()` (only in that instance, currently this isn't working for users of any role though)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what has been causing this issue.

It appears that there is a bug in jQuery (which is used by ASP for validation) which causes invalid date validation within Google Chrome.

To fix this I've added the following into my `_Layout.cshtml` file underneath the script includes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "date",
            function (value, element) {
                var bits = value.match(/([0-9]+)/gi), str;
                if (!bits)
                    return this.optional(element) || false;
                str = bits[1] + '/' + bits[0] + '/' + bits[2];
                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(str));
            },
            ""
            );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You've told the model validator that you are going to use the d'/'MM'/'yyyy format and you have `ApplyFormatInEditMode` true.

Comment: I've tried setting this to false, doesn't seem to make any difference.